# Настройка шлюза в подсеть

Tags: linux, подсети, шлюз

есть ПК внутри vpn сети (10.8.0.0/24)

внутри этой же сети есть сервак с линуксом, который имеет доступ в подсеть (10.10.0.0/24)

Задача: дать доступ ПК в подсеть 10.10.0.0

Как я понимаю, нужно сделать сервер шлюзом и настроить маршрутизацию.
Маршрут на ПК я прописал, указав шлюзом IP сервера.

Проблема в том, что никак не могу найти информацию о том, как настроить шлюз на конкретную подсеть. Постоянно натыкаюсь только на то, «как расшарить инетик».

Как это делается? Как создать шлюз на сиске или длинке я знаю, а вот с сервером — чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, `iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: *как расшарить инетик* — фактически, это оно самое и есть. // для помощи вам в диагностике проблем приведите, пожалуйста, вывод `ip a; ip r` на всех трёх ключевых точках — «пк внутри сети», «серваке», «компьютере внутри подсети 10.10.0.0/24»

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

если на компьютерах в подсети шлюзом по умолчанию указано использование того самого сервера, который вы настраиваете, то достаточно:

- разрешить на этом сервере передачу пакетов между интерфейсами:

  ```
  $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ```

  для того, чтобы эта настройка применялась и после перезагрузки, раскомментируйте (или добавьте, если нет) строку в `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

  ```
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- проконтролировать, что эти пакеты не искажаются и не блокируются *netfilter-ом* (см. вывод `$ sudo iptables-save`).

если же на этих компьютерах шлюзом по умолчанию служит другая машина (или вообще таковой не задан), то, в дополнение к разрешению передачи пакетов между интерфейсами, вам ещё придётся эти пакеты «искажать».

как минимум потребуется подмена адреса источника у пакетов, поступивших на «внешний» интерфейс, и адресованных компьютерам подсети, а также обратная подмена адреса назначения у «ответных» пакетов.

оба данных действия может выполнять директива *netfilter-а* под названием *snat* (*source nat*). пример её добавления с помощью программы *iptables*:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o интерфейс -j SNAT --to-source ip-адрес
```

где:

- `интерфейс` — это имя сетевого интерфейса, через который данный компьютер подключен к целевой подсети
- `ip-адрес` — адрес, закреплённый за данным интерфейсом

Comment: У `iptables` по умолчанию выбирается таблица `filter`, а `SNAT` выполняется в таблице `nat`, поэтому к команде нужно ещё добавить `-t nat`.

Comment: ... да и `-m tcp -p tcp`, пожалуй, лишние... ;-)

Comment: @kff, спасибо, исправил копипаст.