# Раздать интернет в локальную сеть

Tags: linux, сеть

У меня есть домашняя сеть на два компьютера. Первый (c linux mint 17.2 64 bit) - это тот, который подключен к интернету через кабель, и от него же идет кабель ко второму (с windows).

Сетевые карточки определились, интернет есть и сеть тоже есть, но я не могу раздать интернет. На компьютере с windows написано "без доступа к Интернету", хотя на линуксовом пишет, что подключение есть.

Как мне раздать интернет на оба компьютера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

копия [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541091/178576) на идентичный по сути, но иной по форме вопрос:

---

если на компьютерах в подсети шлюзом по умолчанию указано использование того самого сервера, который вы настраиваете, то достаточно:

- разрешить на этом сервере передачу пакетов между интерфейсами:

  ```
  $ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ```

  для того, чтобы эта настройка применялась и после перезагрузки, раскомментируйте (или добавьте, если нет) строку в `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

  ```
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- проконтролировать, что эти пакеты не искажаются и не блокируются *netfilter-ом* (см. вывод `$ sudo iptables-save`).
- добавить правило *netfiler-а* для подмены адреса отправителя у пакетов, поступивших с «внутреннего» интерфейса, и уходящих на внешний интерфейс:

  ```
  $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o внешний_интерфейс -j MASQUERADE
  ```

если же на этих компьютерах шлюзом по умолчанию служит другая машина (или вообще таковой не задан), то, в дополнение к разрешению передачи пакетов между интерфейсами, вам ещё придётся эти пакеты «искажать».

как минимум потребуется подмена адреса источника у пакетов, поступивших на «внешний» интерфейс, и адресованных компьютерам подсети, а также обратная подмена адреса назначения у «ответных» пакетов.

оба данных действия может выполнять директива *netfilter-а* под названием *snat* (*source nat*). пример её добавления с помощью программы *iptables*:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o внутренний_интерфейс -j SNAT --to-source ip-адрес
```

где `ip-адрес` — адрес, закреплённый за «внутренним» интерфейсом.

---

для того, чтобы не вводить упомянутые выше одну или две команды (`iptables ...`) после каждой перезагрузки настраиваемого сервера, их можно добавить, например, в конец файла `/etc/rc.local`, но **до** строки `exit 0`, которая там обычно присутствует (если нет — просто добавляйте в конец файла). добавка `sudo`, конечно, в этом файле не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ частично помог. Т.е. "на бумаге" интернет вроде бы подцепился. И на компьютере с windows в самом соединении написано что интернет подключен. Но самого его нет, т.е. браузер и другие программы в интернет вылезти не могут

Работает только торрент

Comment: небось, имена не резолвятся на клиентах. укажите **на клиентах** рабочий nameserver. например, провайдерский, или  какой-нибудь публичный: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554664/178576

Comment: да, я поправил этот файл вот так
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 192.168.137.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 4.2.2.2
но это не помогло

Comment: я же подчеркнул — **на клиентах**, а не на сервере.

Comment: тут не рекомендовано писать пустой комментарий, но все же большое спасибо. Очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать интернет шлюз.

Например:
На Linux машине

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

192.168.1.0/24-домашняя подсесть.

В windows в свойствах протокола TCP/IP4 прописывается  в первой строке IP домашней подсети например 192.168.0.2, 
во второй Маска подсети например 255.255.255.0 ,
Основной шлюз 192.168.0.1

Comment: `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` — проверяйте, пожалуйста, прежде чем предлагать неработающие команды.