# Настройка интернета в локальной сети на базе сервера Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, настройка

Имеется сервер с установленной Ubuntu 18.04, в нем стоит две сетевые карты. К одной приходит интернет от провайдера, вторая смотрит в локальную сеть. Сетевые интерфейсы вроде настроил, компьютеры в сети пингуют друг друга и сервер, на сервере пингуется ya.ru. Но интернета в локалке нет.
Вывод команд

```
vadim@rpu_server:~$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 ::1/128 scope host 

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000

link/ether 9c:d6:43:63:23:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp5s0

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000

link/ether 2c:4d:54:51:99:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 217.71.134.26/28 brd 217.71.134.31 scope global enp6s0

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 2001:b08:a:2800:2e4d:54ff:fe51:9974/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 

valid_lft 2591972sec preferred_lft 604772sec
    inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe51:9974/64 scope link 

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000

link/ether be:35:91:75:3e:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 fe80::bc35:91ff:fe75:3e6b/64 scope link 

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

vadim@rpu_server:~$ ip r

default via 217.71.134.17 dev enp6s0 proto static 

192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 

192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 

217.71.134.16/28 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 217.71.134.26
```

предложенные здесь [раздать сеть в локалку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603471/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)  не помогли, интернета в локальной сети нет

Comment: nat подняли фаерволом или какую-либо проксю?

Comment: @KoVadim, выполнил следующие команды: `$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp5s0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1` и `$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE`, enp6s0  - внешний интерфейс, enp5s0 - внутренний (192.168.1.1 его IP)

Comment: покажите ваш `/etc/network/interfaces`
ваши `iptables-rules`
и `/etc/sysctl.conf`